# Pandas: Implementing Breusch-Pagan with Panel data

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels, diagnostics

I am currently using the following code to estimate PanelOLS:

```
Y = df['billsum']

X = df[['years_exp', 'leg_totalbills', 'amtsum', 'amtsumlag.1', 'cfcontrol', 'sen',\
        'Republican']]

X = add_constant(X)

from pandas.stats.plm import PanelOLS
reg=PanelOLS(Y,X,time_effects=True)

print('MODEL 1: OLS Regression Results',reg)

MODEL 1: OLS Regression Results 
-------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------

Formula: Y ~ <const> + <years_exp> + <leg_totalbills> + <amtsum> + <amtsumlag.1>
             + <cfcontrol> + <sen> + <Republican>

Number of Observations:         6930
Number of Degrees of Freedom:   17

R-squared:         0.7081
Adj R-squared:     0.7074

Rmse:              0.2423

F-stat (8, 6913):  1048.1396, p-value:     0.0000

Degrees of Freedom: model 16, resid 6913

-----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
      Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         const     0.0000        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
     years_exp     0.0205     0.0005      43.71     0.0000     0.0196     0.0214
leg_totalbills     0.0148     0.0005      32.94     0.0000     0.0139     0.0157
        amtsum    -0.0003     0.0001      -3.17     0.0015    -0.0005    -0.0001
   amtsumlag.1     0.0005     0.0001       5.03     0.0000     0.0003     0.0007
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     cfcontrol     0.3629     0.0168      21.61     0.0000     0.3299     0.3958
           sen     0.0598     0.0177       3.38     0.0007     0.0251     0.0944
    Republican     0.6540     0.0114      57.38     0.0000     0.6317     0.6764
---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------
```

I want to do the Breusch-Pagan test for Heteroskedasticity:

```
statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.het_breushpagan(resid, exog_het)
```

I know that I am supposed to input the residuals (probably in array format) and the exog_het which in my case would be `X`. The problem is that I do not know how to get the `PanelOLS`to ouput the residuals. Actually, I'm not sure if the residuals is actually the `Std Err` reported in the `PanelOLS` output. So, the question: Where does the residual show in the `regression output` and how can I get Pandas to output it independently so that I can input it into the `Breusch-Pagan` test.

Comment: I'm just reading through the github docs, have you tried reg._resid_raw?

Comment: @ flyingmeatball: Yes, that is it! This is a little embarrassing, but can you comment a link to the github_docs?

Comment: I just googled the package you're having trouble with (pandas.stats.plm) and it was the first link: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/stats/plm.py  The PanelOLS class starts at line 28.  Hope that helps!